# gitlab 5.1 new added ssh key for new user works only after a day (push/clone)

Tags: ssh, git-push, gitlab

My users experience strange thing. When they add their new key, it works only another day to push or clone a repository. I looked into database and authorized_keys file and keys are there. I can't find anything visible in logs too. It is very annoying. Does somebody know how to solve it?

Gitlab version 5.1.0

```bash
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking Gitlab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version? ... OK (1.3.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ...
Studentas Test / amen6 ... ok

Checking Gitlab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Projects have satellites? ...
Studentas Test / amen6 ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes

Checking GitLab ... Finished

sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p392
Gem Version:    1.8.23
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.0.4

GitLab information
Version:    5.1.0
Revision:   a06d9a4
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        https://host.lt
HTTP Clone URL: https://host.lt/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@host.lt:some-project.git
Using LDAP: yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.3.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
My users experience strange thing. When they add their new key, it works only another day to push or clone a repository. I looked into database and authorized_keys file and keys are there. 
Gitlab version 5.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

5.1 was known to have to issue keeping ssh authorize_keys in sync with the database, as in [issue 3968](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3968), a slightly different issue.

Considering that issue doesn't seem relevant in the latest 5.3 or 6.0pre version, the first thing would be to upgrade and see if that problem persists.

Comment: I am using gitlab 6.2 and have the same problem. The keys do not end up in the authorized_keys file. I have not waited a day though. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646780/gitlab-6-2-not-syncing-with-authorized-keys)